# react-native-touch-id : custom text on native error

Tags: android, react-native

My app have provided language, in `react-native-touch-id` doc only have few word in android dialog can be custom, I wonder how to also custom native error ? Below is an example
[image: IMG_20190918_223155]

Comment: Analyze the inside of the module and find it.

Comment: @hongdevelop I had find all the file, but totally can't find the word, this is weird